# Alternative phrase for "makes sense" (used in arguments)

Tags: synonyms

An idea I have for an alternative is 'is consistent'. But I'm looking for something that's better.

I *am* looking for a succinct answer that implies consistency, and to be used in arguments.

Comment: The idea *is logical/lacks logic*?

Comment: it "works" or "fits"?

Comment: @WS2 I think 'is logical' might be too vague -- unless 'logical' has a strict definition I'm unaware of

Comment: @Tom *Follows the usually accepted rules of logic*.  That seems to me a lot less vague than saying something *makes sense*, or, heaven forbid, *works*, or *fits*.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I think you're right: Oxford says: "Characterized by or capable of clear, sound reasoning". So if you add it, I'll accept

Comment: In informal settings with friends you could say “it/that computes” if “it makes sense,” although it’s usually used in the negative: “it/that does not compute” when the proposition “makes no sense [at all].  Otherwise “it’s reasonable” might work if you think that’s any less vague than the first (and best, imo) suggestion made by @WS2 right out of the gate.

Comment: ***Sensible.***

Comment: For something that is wrong or inconsistent, "It does not compute" (said in a monotone) is idiomatic to folks of my generation.  However, "It does compute" would just get you dumb looks, even in an AARP meeting.  (Though, come to think of it, there are probably Spockisms that would be more familiar to the younger crowd and which could be used in the positive sense.)

Comment: I've never heard *That computes* - must be American.

Comment: @WS2 - You had to have watched [*Lost in Space*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058824/?ref_=nv_sr_2) in the 60s.  (And, as I said, the only recognized phrase is "It does not compute.").

Comment: @HotLicks No, lost on me I'm afraid. I've just thought, however, how people say, idiomatically, *It doesn't add up*. e.g. *There is something in what the witness is telling us which doesn't add up*. That is in widespread use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm happy with '**is logical**', because I didn't know before that 'logical' included this definition: 'Characterized by or capable of clear, sound reasoning'.

'Sound' being defined in argumentation as 'valid and premises are true'.

Answer (score 5):

I wish I knew if you want something formal or informal, and I wish we had some context.

Others have offered some nice formal alternatives -- here are some informal ones.

Gotcha.

I'm with you, (brother/sister).

Sounds good (so far).

Yes, that follows.

I won't argue with you (there/on that).

Yes, that jives.

I can relate.

Sure.

I see your point/logic.

Yes, yes.

Of course.

That's clear.

Yes, (obviously).

Goes without saying.

No question.

Absolutely.

Okay.

No disagreement (with that).

I feel you, (brother).

I see where you're coming from.

Right.

No doubt.

Without a doubt.

Go on....

(Perfectly) understandable.

Answer (score 2):

***Reasonable***

> **rea·son·able** adjective
>
> 1
>
> a :  being in agreement with right thinking or right judgment :  not
>   conflicting with reason :  not absurd :  not ridiculous
>
> *a reasonable conviction>*
>
> b :  being or remaining within the bounds of reason :  not extreme : 
>   not excessive
>
> *a reasonable request*
>
> *a reasonable hope of succeeding*
>
> *spent a reasonable amount of time in relaxation*
>
> *is of a reasonable size*
>
> **Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary**

Answer (score 1):

*[Cogent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cogent)*:

> adjective
>
> (Of an argument or case) clear, logical, and convincing:
>
> *they put forward **cogent** arguments for British membership*
>
> *the newspaper’s lawyers must prepare a **cogent** appeal*

*oxforddictionaries.com*

Answer (score 0):

The idea *follows the usually accepted rules of logic*.

Comment: I think the 'follows the usually accepted rules' part is redundant: the definition states that the reasoning is 'sound', which means the argumentation is valid and its premises are true

Answer (score 0):

Your idea has some **foundation**.  (sound foundations, moral foundations, etc)

> - foundation (noun) "something (such as an idea, a principle, or a fact) that provides support for something" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foundation)

e.g.

- These problems threaten the foundations of our modern society.
- There is little foundation for your objections, sir.